# Can we use "Our discussion with somebody indicates that..."?

Tags: passive-voice, sentence-choice

As the caption refers to, the specific context is that: I discussed this matter with my customer and was advised that....So, could I use this structure instead (to make it more formal) "Our discussion with my customer indicated that...". I use the latter because I saw it on one book (but now I couldn't remember which book).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's an "sb"?

Comment: Sorry, can you make it clearer?

Comment: A discussion cannot indicate. Give more context. Maybe: My customer and I have discussed this matter and came to a conclusion that...

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice), as opposed to [active voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_voice). Instead of saying "my customer said ..." or "the customer indicated that ..." or "we learned ... while talking to the customer," you use passive voice to shift subject away from the "actual" subject. While passive voice can have its uses, it sounds odd, and is often used in some contexts to hide the subject from the sentence.

> Active: I made the decision
>
> Passive: The decision was made
>
> Active: We laid you off
>
> Passive: You were laid off